# Text Boxes Not Populating from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Framework: ASP.NET 4.5 | Database: MSMMS

My demo application is supposed to populate textboxes with dynamic data when a selection is made from a dropdown list. I've added a button, that when pressed fires, an OnClick event that is supposed to assign values from the DB to the appropriate textboxes. Right now my code looks like:

```
protected void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        API_DatabaseEntities1 db = new API_DatabaseEntities1();
        var customer = (from c in db.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == 4
                        select c).FirstOrDefault();

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return;

        }

        if (ddlCustomer.SelectedValue == "Marisol") {

            tbDescription.Text = customer.ToString();
            tbFName.Text = customer.Fname;
            tbSocial.Text = customer.SSN;
            tbDOB.Text = customer.DOB.ToString();
            tbFName1.Text = customer.Fname;
            tbMName.Text = customer.Mname; 
            tbLName.Text = customer.Lname;
            tbPrimaryPhone.Text = customer.PrimaryPhone;
            tbSecondaryPhone.Text = customer.SecondaryPhone;
            tbAdd1.Text = customer.Address;
            tbCity.Text = customer.City;
            tbZip.Text = customer.Zip;
            tbEmail.Text = customer.Email;
            tbMonLease.Text = customer.MortLeaseAmt;
            tbEmployer.Text = customer.Employer;
            tbPosition.Text = customer.Position;
            tbHireDate.Text = customer.HireDate.ToString();
            tbWorkPhone.Text = customer.WorkPhone;
            tbGross.Text = customer.GrossIncome; 

        }

        Debug.WriteLine(tbPosition.Text);


    }
```

When the button is clicked, the page sends a request to the DB, but the textboxes remain blank. I am returning a value from the database, but it's not populating. Here is some code from my front page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 

    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomer" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Fname" DataValueField="CustomerID"></asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:APIConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [Fname], [Lname] FROM [Customer] ORDER BY [Fname]"></asp:SqlDataSource><br /><br />

    <asp:Button ID="btnChoose" runat="server" Text="Choose Test Case" OnClick="btnChoose_Click" /><br /><br />

 Description of Goods and/or Services:<asp:TextBox ID="tbDescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
<div>
 Membership #:<asp:TextBox ID="tbMembership" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> Ext.: <asp:TextBox ID="tbExt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
 First Name:<asp:TextBox ID="tbFName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /> <br /><br />

  Soc Sec No.: <asp:TextBox ID="tbSocial" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> Date of Birth:<asp:TextBox ID="tbDOB" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</div><br /> <br />
```

I'm not sure if the problem is from the code behind or from the front page design. Any help would be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure there is data coming from DB?

Comment: @Shaharyar I'm pretty sure. When running a debug, the debug processes through the If Statement checking for null returns, without exiting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is checking for a selection in the drop-down list of the name "Marisol" - however, the "Value" field of the drop-down list is configured to use the CustomerID column.  So this code populating the fields will never execute.

Maybe you should instead be using `ddlCustomer.SelectedValue` in the WHERE clause of your query.

Comment: I like your idea. Could you show me an example of what you mean by using ddlCustomer.SelectedValue in the WHERE clause?